# The solution of a discrete, linear system by knowing eigenvalues and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

I have the equation
$$\underline{x}(t+1) = \textbf{A}\,\underline{x}(t)\, ,\quad (1)$$
where $\underline{x}$ is the $n$-dimensional vector of unknowns and $\textbf{A}$ is a $n\times n$ numerical matrix. I know that $\textbf{A}$ is diagonalizable and that it admits

- an eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ with eigenvector $\underline{x}_1$
- eigenvalues $\lambda_2=\dots=\lambda_{n_1}$ with eigenvectors $\{\underline{x}_2,\dots, \underline{x}_{n_1}\}$
- an eigenvalue $\lambda_{n_1+1}$ with eigenvector $\underline{x}_{n_1+1}$
- eigenvalues $\lambda_{n_1+2}=\dots=\lambda_{n}$ with eigenvectors $\{\underline{x}_{n_1+2},\dots, \underline{x}_{n}\}$

How can I calculate the solution of Eq. (1), $\underline{x}(t)$?

Comment: What have you tried? For instance, do you see why $x(t) = A^t x(0)$? What happens if you write $A = PDP^{-1}$ using its eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: @CadeReinberger yes, I can write $P^{-1} x(t+1)=D P^{-1} x(t)$ and then $y(t)=D^t y(0)$ where $y(t)=P^{-1} x(t)$. But I wonder if there exist a discrete version of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_differential_equation